# Font family in css not working

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I am using `YanoneKaffeesatz` Font in my wordpress website. So to use this font first I generated code from [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator). Then I got this piece of code

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'yanone_kaffeesatz_lightRg';
src: url('yanonekaffeesatz-light-webfont.eot');
src: url('yanonekaffeesatz-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('yanonekaffeesatz-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('yanonekaffeesatz-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('yanonekaffeesatz-light-webfont.svg#yanone_kaffeesatz_lightRg') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Then I paste the code in my css file and paste all the converted fonts(.otf,.svg, .ttf) in my website folder but still my font has not been changed. So can some one tell me why this is happening?
Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.

Comment: You really need to show your directory structure for problems like this. It's impossible to see if you have the correct paths in use for the fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Are the font files in the same dir as your stylesheet? You're currently pointing to that dir. Paths in CSS are relative to the stylesheet, not the root.

```
root 
  -css/styles.css
  -images/
  -fonts/
  index.html
```

With the above structure you would use this as your URL.

```
url('../fonts/your_font.font;);
```

Comment: yes...as in wordpress my css file is in the root folder and also my fonts are also in the same folder.

Comment: Why is your CSS in the root? Shouldn't it be in your theme?

Comment: Can you please post your development URl so we can check the problem ? I'm pretty sure @SpaceBeers is right

Comment: sorry but it is in my localhost.and my css file is in the same folder as because in wordpress already the file was in that root folder so I just used that

Comment: Your CSS should be in your theme folder, not the root. Could you edit your question with a structure "diagram" like I've used?